# Need to run some code after Repeater DataBind event

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am writing a program for car parking lots; it's near complete but I'm working or reports and need to make the data easy and dependable; for this I have a repeater; after `DataBind` event; I want to use a 'loop' to apply forecolors to internal repeater labels that hold certain text results after databind; as well as display a timespan calculated using `DateTime.Now` - the date in the databound label. The code I have only applies to the first result in the repeater.

`FIndAny` is a small class to access internal controls; please ignore; just help me with sample code on how I can do something like this.

Here are code examples:

```
Repeater1.DataBind();
//int i=0;
//Label dc = c;
foreach (RepeaterItem t in Repeater1.Items)
{
    ((Label)(FIndAny(Repeater1, "Label41"))).Text = 
        Convert.ToString((DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(((Label)(FIndAny(Repeater1, "Label9"))).Text)).TotalHours);
}     

Label6.Text = "View Time trace below...";
Label lbl = ((Label)FIndAny(Repeater1, "Label11"));

if (((Label)FIndAny(Repeater1, "Label13")).Text == "Parked" && (mdx.cardstatus.Where(x => x.CardNum == lbl.Text)).All(x => x.Status == 1))
{
    ((Panel)FIndAny(Repeater1, "Panel1")).BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    ((Panel)FIndAny(Repeater1, "Panel1")).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
    ((Panel)FIndAny(Repeater1, "Panel1")).BorderWidth = 5;
    ((Label)FIndAny(Repeater1, "Label13")).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    ((Label)FIndAny(Repeater1, "Label13")).Font.Bold = true;
    ((Label)FIndAny(Repeater1, "Label13")).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Repeater.ItemDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which occurs after an item in the Repeater control is data-bound but before it is rendered on the page.

```
    Repeater1.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(Repeater1ItemDataBound);
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}

void Repeater1ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
        Label label13 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label13");
        if (label13.Text == "Parked") {
        //..... etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on aspx page

```
<asp:Repeater OnItemDataBound="Repeater_ItemDataBound" ID="Repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then on code-behind

```
protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Label myLabel = e.Item.FindControl("MyLabel") as Label;
        YourItemObject itemObject = e.Item.DataItem as YourItemObject;
        myLabel.Text = itemObject.SomeAttribute;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)